# Seamless fading between multiple elements on hover (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Very new at jquery, but I'm looking to fade between backgrounds (in this case, multiple alternative divs housed in a parent div) on hovering over buttons. My current code is functional in that regard, however only to the extent that you hover over the button, then mouseout. However if you go from one button directly to another without mousing out, it breaks the hover and will throw off the order that the buttons call their respective divs.

Could anyone help me with this in a way that would utilize a seamless fadeIn/Out between these elements? I'm open to other methods if they are more efficient (and any help whatsoever with drying up my amateur code would be outstanding).

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#b1').hover(function() {
    if ($('.int').is(":visible")) {
      $('.int').fadeOut(300);

    } else {
      $("#i1").fadeIn(1000)
    }

  });

  $('#b2').hover(function() {
    if ($('.int').is(":visible")) {
      $('.int').fadeOut(300);

    } else {
      $("#i2").fadeIn(1000)
    }

  });

  $('#b3').hover(function() {
    if ($('.int').is(":visible")) {
      $('.int').fadeOut(300);

    } else {
      $("#i3").fadeIn(1000)
    }

  });



});
```

```css
    .hold {
      background: green;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0 auto;
      float: left;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 0;
    }
    .int {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      float: left;
      display: none;
    }
    #i1 {
      background: red;
    }
    #i2 {
      background: blue;
    }
    #i3 {
      background: orange;
    }
    #b1 {
      background: purple;
      height: 50px;
      width: 80px;
      float: left;
    }
    #b2 {
      background: purple;
      height: 50px;
      width: 80px;
      float: left;
    }
    #b3 {
      background: purple;
      height: 50px;
      width: 80px;
      float: left;
    }
    .banner {
      width: 100%;
      height: 70px;
      background: purple;
      margin: 0px auto;
      z-index: 3;
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 15px;
    }
    * {
      margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="banner">
    <button id="b1">
    </button>
    <button id="b2">
    </button>
    <button id="b3">
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="hold" id="hold1">
    <div class="int" id="i1">
    </div>
    <div class="int" id="i2">
    </div>
    <div class="int" id="i3">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Could you write what is the expected result of a sequence of hovers ? Let's say for example my mouse hovers the background, then goes to the first rectangle, then the second, then the third, what are the expected changes in colors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't 100% sure if this sort of effect was what you were going for. As below, the fadeOut happens and then is immediately succeeded by the fadeIn of the new colour. Anyway, check this out and see if it helps.

Add these custom HTML attributes to your buttons.

```
<button id="b1" data-intId="#i1"></button>
<button id="b2" data-intId="#i2"></button>
<button id="b3" data-intId="#i3"></button>
```

Then, modify your JavaScript as follows

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var ints = $('.int'); // I'm not really sure what 'int' refers to
    var buttons = $('button'); // could be changed if more buttons added later, maybe using a class, like int

    buttons.mouseenter(function () {
        var newInt = $(this).attr('data-intId');
        $(newInt).fadeIn(1000);
    });

    buttons.mouseout(function() {
        if (ints.is(":visible")) {
            ints.fadeOut(300);
        }
    })

});
```

A couple of notes about drying up your code (you'll see in my notes above) - firstly try to save any important, frequently recurring selectors as variables. This will not only help you to write, but is also cheaper in terms of performance. Every time you're sending out your little jQuery leprechaun* to find a selector in the DOM tree, it's using up resources. If you can find whatever you need straight away, then store those elements, it's much better.

Also, I took the opportunity to use HTML's data-* attributes, which you can create entirely at your own free will. Here I created one which holds the ID of the div you want to bring to the fore.

One final piece of advice from me if to be more descriptive with your naming. Things like 'int', 'i1' and 'b1' may be fine for these cases, but once your project grows or someone else works on it too, you could waste a lot of time figuring out what you called something and why.

*jQuery leprechaun is certainly not an official term (as far as I'm aware), it just came to me spontaneously. Also note I'm not a jQuery expert, I only started a couple of months ago.

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you so much! And the tips on drying my code is much appreciated :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute starts with selector, attribute equals selector `.finish()` , `.filter()`, `String.prototype.slice()`

```
  $("[id^=b]").hover(function() {
    $("[id^=i]").finish().filter("[id=i" + this.id.slice(-1) + "]").fadeIn(1000)
  }, function() {
    $("[id^=i]").finish().fadeOut(1000)
  })
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("[id^=b]").hover(function() {
    $("[id^=i]").finish().filter("[id=i" + this.id.slice(-1) + "]").fadeIn(1000)
  }, function() {
    $("[id^=i]").finish().fadeOut(1000)
  })


});
```

```css
.hold {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
.int {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  display: none;
}
#i1 {
  background: red;
}
#i2 {
  background: blue;
}
#i3 {
  background: orange;
}
#b1 {
  background: purple;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
}
#b2 {
  background: purple;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
}
#b3 {
  background: purple;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
}
.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: purple;
  margin: 0px auto;
  z-index: 3;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="banner">
    <button id="b1">
    </button>
    <button id="b2">
    </button>
    <button id="b3">
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="hold" id="hold1">
    <div class="int" id="i1">
    </div>
    <div class="int" id="i2">
    </div>
    <div class="int" id="i3">
    </div>
  </div>
```